# Can I update binary if status already "Ready for Sale" in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My application's status is "Ready for Sale". But I set release date in 1 month. I found critical bug and want to re-upload my binary with the same version.

Can I do that or need to wait before it will be released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to put out a new version. But keep in mind the review time: some customers may experience the bug and give you bad ratings. Best to test thoroughly **before** you release.

Answer (score 1):

no you cannot. You have to release it and then create a new version and upload another binary. At this point there is no way to "developer reject" the binary